# Creating Nested Dictionaries in Python

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

I am having some issues in converting a dictionary of data frames to a nested dictionary. I have a dictionary called `isc_r` which is of length 20. Each of the 20 key contains a dataframe which has 268 items. I was trying to convert the data frame to a dictionary for each key but it is not exactly what I wish to have.

```
x = {}
for i in range(len(isc_r)):
  x[i] = isc_r[i].to_dict()
```

It is currently returning me something like this: `{0: {0: {0: 0.07961916939125185}, 1: {0: 0.09932054687328157}..... 267: {0: -0.010788695928004022}}, 1: {0: {0: 0.10486062116344974}, 1: {0: 0.12926987936131362}, 2: {0: 0.043314190833473876}`.

But I wish to have something like this: `{0: {0: 0.07961916939125185, 1: 0.09932054687328157..... 267: -0.010788695928004022}}, {1: {0: 0.10486062116344974, 1: 0.12926987936131362...}}...`. Hence, I need to remove the additional layer in the current dictionary. Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: To dict has some arguments, is `to_dict('records')` what you are looking for? See [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) for more possible arguments.

Comment: So you have dict of dataframes and want to convert it to dict of dicts? Sounds like a straightforward task. Extra nested level seems to come from columns cause dataframes have columns. If frames have a single column use `squeeze - isc_r[i].squeeze().to_dict()` to convert frame to series.

Comment: Thank you so much @Poolka. It worked like a charm.